# In WPF Can I have a button event in the MainWindow.xaml reference code in my own class?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, click

I am creating a WPF application that has multiple functions.  I am trying to learn how to have a class for each function of the application.  For example I have a function to allow the user to select a database, table, etc. On the WPF window I have a button to load the table list once the database has been selected or typed in.  I would like the click event of the Load DB Info button to reference code in my DatabaseInfo.cs code instead of the MainWindow.xaml.cs.  I would like to do this for all the events for this function.  Is it possible to do this?

Here is my xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="TextUtilities.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextUtilities"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Text Utilites" x:Name="TextUtils" Height="420" Width="900" Left="100" Top="30" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="#FFDBF4FB">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtRLFDBTitle" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                 Text="Process to clean a database table and create a pipe delimited text file. You may type in a server instance or select one from the list.  Once a server is choosen please cliack the 'Load DB Info' button." 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="62" Margin="10,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="659" FontFamily="Arial" 
                 FontSize="16" Padding="5,1,1,1" Background="#FFE8F9FF" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblRLFDBInstance" Content="Enter Database Instance:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="5,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbxRLFDBInstances" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="189,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" IsEditable="True"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnRLFDBLoadDBInfo" Content="Load DB Info" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="475,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" Click="dbi:btnRLFDBLoadDBInfo_Click" Background="#FFEEFFFF" ToolTip="Click here after choosing or typing in the datbase instance.  This will populate the database list."/>
        <Label x:Name="lblRLFDBName" Content="Choose Database:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="5,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbxRLFDBName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="189,132,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" IsEditable="True" SelectionChanged="cbxRLFDBName_SelectionChanged" ToolTip="Once a database is choosen the table list will automatically be populated."/>
        <Label x:Name="lblRLFDBTableName" Content="Choose Table:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="5,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbxRLFTableName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="189,177,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" IsEditable="True" SelectionChanged="cbxRLFTableName_SelectionChanged"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblRLFDBOutputName" Content="Choose Output Folder:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="5,233,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtRLFDBOutputFolder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="189,222,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" TextChanged="txtRLFDBOutputFolder_TextChanged"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnRLFDBBrowseFolder" Content="Browse..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="475,235,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" Click="btnRLFDBBrowseFolder_Click" Background="#FFEEFFFF" ToolTip="CHoose the folder where the text file will be saved to.  The file will be named the same as a the table with '_duc' appended to the end."/>
        <Button x:Name="btnRLFDBSubmit" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="261,300,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" Click="btnRLFDBSubmit_Click" Background="#FFEEFFFF"/>
    </Grid>
</Window?
```

Here is what I have in the DatabaseInfo.cs class.

```
using System.Windows;
```

namespace TextUtilities
{
    class DatabaseInfo
    {

```
    public void MakeVisibleRLFDatabaseComponents(bool blnVisible)
    {
        if (blnVisible)
        {
            ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).grdRLFDatabase.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).Height = 430;
        }
        else
        {
            ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).grdRLFDatabase.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).Height = 420;
        }
    }


    public btnRLFDBLoadDBInfo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool blnSuccess = false;


        cbxDBName.Items.Clear();
        cbxTableName.Items.Clear();

        blnSuccess = GetDBNames(sqlConn);

        if (blnSuccess)
        {
            GetTableNames(sqlConn);
            Check_DB_Submit_Button();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: A variety of solutions exist. You can subscribe directly using code-behind. You could write your own XAML extension to handle the scenario. But really, you should just not use the `Click` event in the first place. Instead, learn about `ICommand` and bind your `ICommand` object to the `Button.Command` property. You can have a separate `ICommand` object for each button/command, or you can use a delegating implementation (such as the `RelayCommand` or `DelegateCommand` classes easily found throughout Stack Overflow and MVVM libraries) to refer to command-handling implementations.

Comment: @Peter Duniho -- I am working through this and it looks like what I need.  Thank you.  Can I add one more piece to this?  In this DatabaseInfo class I need to reference the objects from my WPF window, like a textbox.  The only way I have seen to do this is ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).txtInputName.Text.  Is this the only way?  Can I or should I have xaml files for each function I want to do?  Currently each function is a grid within the MainWindow.xaml.

Comment: _"I need to reference the objects from my WPF window"_ -- well, not if you're using WPF as intended, you don't. You can, as you've done, expose references to elements via fields in the `MainWindow` class. You could have the `MainWindow` class pass those references ahead of time (e.g. after calling `InitializeComponent()` and after creating the command class). You could probably even use the `Button` reference as a starting point to walk your visual tree to find other controls.

Comment: But the _correct_ way to do it is for every UI property that you want to interact with to be bound to a view model property somewhere and use the view model properties in your commands. A typical strategy in that approach is to use one of those delegating `ICommand` implementations I mentioned, and have them delegate to commands in the view model that has the properties you want to affect, or a view model that has a reference to the view model with those properties.